# MongoDB update with date comparison

Tags: mongodb

I want to update a MongoDB collection with createddate less than 30 days of current date.

```
db.transactions.updateMany({  <createdDate lessthan 30 days>  }, {$set:{isexpired: true }})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$lt` operator to compare with an absolute date(in this case 1 month ago from now).

eg. =>

```
db.transactions.updateMany(
  {'createddate':{'$lt':ISODate('2022-10-29T18:30:00.000+00:00')}}, 
  {$set:{isexpired: true }}
)
```

Comment: I want to update only the records after 30 days from createddate.
CreatedDate > ( new Date() - 30 ) days

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to update all records where createddate lies between (today) and (today-30 days), in that case you can use a range query on 'createddate' field.
which would look like this -> 


db.transactions.updateMany({'createddate':{'$gt':ISODate('2022-10-29T18:30:00.000+00:00'),'$lt':ISODate('2022-11-29T18:30:00.000+00:00')}}, {$set:{isexpired: true }})

Comment: I have tried to store current date time to local variable for comparison, but this is storing only the expression not the result value

const dte =
{
   $dateSubtract:
      {
         startDate: new Date(),
         unit: "month",
         amount: 1
      }
}

Comment: Then better create a view. Otherwise you would need to update the collection every Second.

Comment: I have solved the issue with storing the expiry date while creating document.

     const crDate = new Date()
     db.pindetails.updateMany({isExpired: false, expDateTime: {$lt: crDate } },{$set:{isExpired: true }})